# How to place an uploaded picture into the webpage (Jquery)

Tags: php, jquery

I want to show an uploaded image on the web. I'm using a plugin called Dropzone to upload the pictures but I don know how to recover and display them on the page.

This is the php I'm using to upload the images:

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';  

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                      

$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  

$targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); /

}
?>
```

edit: I want to show the image on the same page, removing the uploading box and replacing it with the image with JQuery/php

Comment: Typically you'd need to store this information in the database so you know where the file was saved to reference it in the future. Displaying the image within that code would be as simple as adding <img src="<?php echo $targetFile; ?> /> ... but I'm assuming you probably want to output this image somewhere other than on the same page you uploaded it?

Comment: After saving the image somewhere in your DB, I believe you would use PHP to generate a change in your page's structure (generate a container for new image, and inject it into existing structure), and then trigger either a full-refresh, or use something like lazy-loading to display the change (image).

Comment: security-sidenote: make sure to sanitize/validate the user supplied filename in ['file']['name']; keyword: dir traversal.